# what means $ (ampersand) in a command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

what means the $ at the begin of this command?

```
$ bash testscript
```

If I run the command with $, the result is "command not found"

Comment: $ is a dollar sign, & is an ampersand. In the above context $ represents the shell command prompt. In $var it denotes a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash the '$' sign **means** that a **normal user** logged into the system can execute a command. If you're logged in as **the root user**, the prompt is '#' (hash or number symbol).

For further reading about the use and history of the prompt, please have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/57575/what-is-the-origin-of-the-unix-dollar-prompt

Comment: In addition to this, it is the _unwritten rule_ that commands executed on the interactive command line are often documented by prefixing them with a `$` followed by a space. This is to indicate that the command can be executed from the command line. Eg. `$ ls -lrt`. In your terminal, on the other hand, it could look like `[user@host] $ ls -lrt`. The `$` is just a short version of `PS1`

Answer (score 1):

> what means the $ at the begin of **this** command?
>
> ```
> $ bash testscript
> ```

It's meant to represent [the prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a real meaning, it's just the "header" of the prompt, which is usually stored in the `PS1` environment variable.

On my computer (Linux subsystem on a Windows computer), this is the situation:

When I open the prompt, this is what I see:

```
scampsd@DESKTOP-37TUCEQ:~$
```

When I ask for the `PS1` environment variable, this is what I see:

```
scampsd@DESKTOP-37TUCEQ:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

(Mind the dollarsign at the end)

When I change that variable, this is what happens:

```
scampsd@DESKTOP-37TUCEQ:~$ export PS1=#
#
```

(no dollarsign anymore)